# LINQ statement with WHERE ID NOT IN clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0, ef-core-8.0

I have the following DB structure:

```
// stores entries like "Easter Monday", "Good Friday"
    PublicHoliday {
    Guid Id;
    String Name;
    DateTime Removed;
    }

// stores specific occurrences of public holidays, for instance Easter Monday is 2024-04-01 this year, but 2025-04-21 next year (go figure)
PublicHolidayDate {
Guid Id;
Guid PublicHolidayId; // foreign key for the PublicHoliday table
DateOnly Date;
DateTime Removed;
}

// this table has an entry if a given office has "disabled" a given public holiday (i.e. they stay open during)
OfficePublicHoliday
{
Guid Id;
Guid OfficeId;
Guid PublicHolidayId; // foreign key for the PublicHoliday table
DateTime Removed;
}
```

I need to write a query either in the EF Core API (db.OfficePublicHolidays.Where(...) ) or in linq, that retrieves all active public holidays in a given time range for a given office.

In SQL it would look like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM PublicHolidayDate phd  INNER JOIN PublicHoliday ph ON 
    ph.Id = phd.PublicHolidayId
WHERE 
    ph.Removed IS NULL
    AND phd.Removed IS NULL 
    AND phd.Date >= @StartDate AND phd.Date <= @EndDate
    AND phd.PublicHolidayId NOT IN 
    (SELECT PublicHolidayId FROM OfficePublicHoliday WHERE OfficeId = @OfficeId AND Removed IS NULL)
```

I've been trying to write this in C#, but I can't wrap my head around the "NOT IN WHERE OfficeId = @OfficeId" bit.

Thank you

Comment: `where !context.OfficePublicHoliday.Any(oph => oph.PublicHolidayId == phd.PublicHolidayId && oph.OfficeId == officeId && oph.Removed == null)`?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation properties can help manage the relationships for you. I would suspect an Office entity could have a collection of OfficePublicHoliday, which reference a PublicHoliday with a collection of PublicHolidayDates.

To get active public holiday dates for a given Office, then you could extract them via:

```
var dates = _context.Offices
    .Where(o => o.OfficeId == officeId)
    .SelectMany(o => o.OfficePublicHolidays
        .Where(oph => !oph.Removed.HasValue && !oph.ph.REmoved.HasValue)
        .SelectMany(oph => oph.PublicHoliday.PublicHolidayDates)
    .Where(phd => !phd.Removed.HasValue)
    .ToList();
```

Basically this would only consider office public holidays that are not removed, and reference public holidays and dates that are not removed. Disclaimer: This is written from memory, the `SelectMany` containing `SelectMany` may need to be a `Select` around a `SelectMany`. I don't have an opportunity to verify that, but the gist of using navigation properties should help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = dbContext.PublicHolidayDates
    .Join(
        dbContext.PublicHolidays,
        phd => phd.PublicHolidayId,
        ph => ph.Id,
        (phd, ph) => new { PublicHolidayDate = phd, PublicHoliday = ph }
    )
    .Where(x => x.PublicHoliday.Removed == null && x.PublicHolidayDate.Removed == null)
    .Where(x => x.PublicHolidayDate.Date >= startDate && x.PublicHolidayDate.Date <= endDate)
    .Where(x => !dbContext.OfficePublicHolidays
        .Where(oph => oph.OfficeId == officeId && oph.Removed == null)
        .Select(oph => oph.PublicHolidayId)
        .Contains(x.PublicHolidayDate.PublicHolidayId)
    )
    .Select(x => x.PublicHolidayDate)
    .ToList();
```